# Magento Sample Data 1.9.2.4 Zip file Error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Today i download new sample data from Magento Website.

Which is `ver 1.9.2.4 and later - Added Oct 11, 2016` as on [Magento Website](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download).

But when i installed that Zip file and Extract it. It Can not Unzip.

I have same error both in my linux and windows Machine.

Is there any bug in that zip file or something wrong with my download ??

If anyone already face same issue than Please add your comment here and suggest me solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of the sample data did you download?
I also had that problem.

The solution is to download the other versions like the gzip one.

Or you can go to:

http://mirror.gunah.eu/magento/sample-data/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mageloads/files/assets/1.9.1.0/magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.gz

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Download the `tar.gz` format from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download). It works fine.